# How to find the percentage of a shape which doesn't have another shape in the original

Tags: geometry, percentages

Question:

The area of an ellipse, width a and height b.

A rectangular photograph measures 15cm by 10cm.
It is put into a frame.

The part of the photographthat can be seen is an ellipse.

Work out the percentage of the photograph that can be shown.

Comment: If a garden is 150 square feet, and you plant potatoes in 32.19027549 square feet of it, what percentage of the garden have you planted?

Comment: I literally just had a facepalm moment. I found the answer as soon as I saw this.

Comment: Usually, facepalm moments mean you just learned something so well that you'll never forget it. Celebration!